# Distibuting $15$ distinguishable balls in $8$ distinguishable boxes

Tags: combinatorics, balls-in-bins

I want to distribute $15$ distinguishable balls into $8$ baskets such that the first $5$ ones contain $10$ balls. Are my calculations correct?

Let's say I have 10 balls, there are $ 5^{10} $ to distribute them amongst the first 5 ones. I have $5$ more balls left and $3$ more cells, and so I can distribute those $5$ in $ 3^5 $ ways. Therefore, the number is:

$ \binom{15}{10}\cdot5^{10}\cdot3^5 $

Comment: Looks correct to me

Comment: How are they distributed ? Uniformly at random or what ?

Comment: @trueblueanil This is a problem about counting the number of possible outcomes. So we choose how to distribute.